# How does Laravel 5.4 Middleware work?

Tags: laravel

I've read manual of Laravel 5 but still don't find a solution for my problem.

My task: I need to run multiple websites on the one codebase.

What have I done for it? I made one main website and create table "sites" where I can add new satellites. It's all worked fine. But now, in front end part, I need to create middleware which will help me to divorce different parts of my engine.

I start to create middleware but I've only found 2 ways of middleware:

1. redirect to the correct URL
2. return $next($request) which means that this middleware will be always working.

I don't need a redirect. I just need one thing:

I need that in my web.php route file I can make routes with my middleware group:

For example:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'site'], function () {
//there will be only routes for my satellites
```

And

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
//There will be another routes which won't be on satellites
```

The problem is if I make a redirect on the main site my middleware still working and going into the cycle.

Is there any way to break middleware and don't going into the certain routes?
I've tried with `HttpException` but I've received only 404 or 500 errors, but I don't need it in this case.

Comment: There are a number of useful packages and tutorials for running multi-tenant Laravel sites. https://www.google.com/search?q=laravel+multi-tenant In your case, a domain-based route group for the main-only routes would probably do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! I will discover it!